# The Lorentz-non-covariance of the Wigner Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, phase-space, wigner-transform

**What does the fact that the Wigner function is not Lorentz-covariant imply?**

My analysis so far led me to the (*probably naive*) understanding that there really is nothing special about it, just that it is not possible for the Wigner function to take into account relativistic effects. But I still do not quite understand whether there is something more subtle going on. Is there more to it?

Comment: As an autocorrelation function of Schrödinger wavefunctions, not Lorentz covariant, the WF lacks that property as well, unsurprisingly. What does this property imply for wavefunctions, in your mind? There are ways to spatchcock relativistic corrections to it.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08975) might be of interest.

Comment: The statement that the Wigner function is not Lorentz covariant, it (probably) contingent on the assumption that the conjugate variables are physically associated with position and momentum. In general, (for example in quantum optics) this association is not valid. Therefore, the Wigner functional can be defined in a Lorentz covariant way in such situations?